# Is there a way of doing an action locally on a UIButtton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, scope

I am setting up a table with an I have this code:

```
UIButton *done = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, 40, 40)];
[done setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[done addTarget:self action:@selector(done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:done];
return cell;
```

This doesn't work beacuse this button is only declared in this scope and I want to simply change its image on this click

Comment: Not regarding the original question (other people already gave a good answer)... If cell is a `UITableViewCell` please add the button to cell.contentView as subview instead on cell. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the image in the `done:` method.

```
- (void)done:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does you done method look like?
I think that if you add a sender argument to the method, you can access the button.

```
- (void)done:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    [button doStuff]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an ivar or a private/public property. So you can change its image from everywhere, for example:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property UIButton *done;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.done = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, 40, 40)];
    [self.done setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.done addTarget:self action:@selector(done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.done];
}

- (void)done:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Do something.. like change image

    [self.done setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

Or you declare the sender as the UIButton, like this:

```
- (void)done:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *done = (UIButton *)sender;

    //Do something with the button
}
```